# How to merge partition in macos catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition

[image][image: please check image]

I want to merge two partitions in mac but can't answer on internet please help

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         350.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         75.0 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         75.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +75.0 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled                761.9 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +75.0 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume Projects                27.1 GB    disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +350.0 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.0 GB    disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     220.0 GB   disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.4 MB    disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                535.7 MB   disk3s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk3s5
```

Comment: Can you give from the terminal (Applications/Utility) the result of the command `diskutil list`. it's more detailed than a picture. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean_JD updated question

Comment: @mosean The diskutil output always helps to clarify the disk  structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to have separate partitions. In what follows I assume you want all the files in all three existing partitions.

I recommend having one partition which is formatted as an APFS container. The container can then have multiple volumes - in your case: `Macintosh HD` and `Projects`. The volumes will all share the 500GB disk, but will not be restricted to particular sizes like your 350GB, 75GB and 75GB.

Before you do anything with your disk structure make sure you have a good backup of everything you need to keep.  The backup of Macintosh HD is in case of mistakes/disasters.  You need a backup of `Projects` and `Untitled` because you will be deleting them.

I apologise for lack of screenshots, but I don't have a free disk or two required to replicate your setup.

The steps are:

1. Check you backups are good.
2. Copy the content of Projects and Untitled to another disk.
3. In  Disk Utility remove the `Projects` and `Untitled` partitions.
4. That will allow the main partition to grow to fill the disk. You should then have one partition of 500GB with a Container which has 2 obvious volumes - under Big Sur or Catalina they will be `Macintosh HD` and `Macintosh HD - Data`.
5. Still in Disk Utility, select the Container and add extra volumes as required. Add `Projects`. The volumes all share the same 500Gb disk space and, by default, will expand as required - only limited by the total of 500GB.  If you want to limit the size of the `Projects` volume, you can do this when creating the volume by using "Size Options" - you may want to set the quota (maximum size).
6. Exit Disk Utility and, using Finder, copy your project data back into the new `Projects` volume. Copy the `Untitled` data into some folders in Macintosh HD - best in your home folder or the `/Users/Shared` folder.

**Warning**: If you have a disaster (due to either your mistake or my incorrect instructions) you will need to do a reinstall of macOS and recover your data from backup!! So make sure your backups are good and you know how to recover.

Finally, do consider if you really need multiple volumes. Everything (folders and files) is much simpler to manage if all your data is in the Macintosh HD volume.  If you don't have a strong reason for multiple volumes then just use one, placing folders under your home folder or /Users/Shared.

Comment: Sorry, I use BS, but should be the same for Catalina. I found Untitled(you are right) hard to read.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks.  To improve it really requires screenshots.

Comment: @Gilby i have updated my question

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Gilby's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419460/how-to-merge-partition-in-macos-catalina/419461#419461) with respect to having the `Projects` volume stored in the same container as the `Macintosh HD` volume. This answer involves merging while attempting to preserve the `Projects` volume in a separate partition.  Here, I assume there is no data to be saved on the `Untitled` volume. You can not directly merge the partition containing the `Untitled` volume into the partition containing the `Macintosh HD` volume, because the partition containing the `Projects` volume is between these two partitions. This answer will clone the `Projects` volume to the partition containing the `Untitled` volume, then merge the partition that contained the original `Projects` volume into the partition containing the `Macintosh HD` volume

> The example used in this answer was taken from a virtual machine with Catalina installed on a much smaller internal drive. The drive was not encrypted.

The steps to clone and merge are given next.

1. Click on the Disk Utility window and then press the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> key combination to insure the proper sidebar is displayed, as shown below.

   [image]
2. First, highlight the `Untitled` volume shown in the sidebar, then select the `Restore` button. For `Restore from:`, select the `Projects` volume, as shown below.

   [image]

   Finally, select the `Restore` button in the popup window. When finished, select the `Done` button. I needed to quit and open the Disk Utility to see the results. There should now be two `Projects` volumes, as shown below.

   [image]
3. Highlight the first `Projects` volume shown in the sidebar, then select the `Partition` button. If necessary, select the `Partition` button in the popup window. With the partition containing the original `Projects` volume highlighted in the pie chart, select the `-` button. The result is shown below.

   [image]

   Next, select the `Apply` button, then the `Partition` button. When finished, select the `Done` button. I quit and opened the Disk Utility to be sure I was seeing the correct results. There should now be one `Projects` volume, as shown below.

   [image]

You are finished.

### Instructions When `Projects` Volume Is Formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

> Since your `Projects` Volume is APFS formatted, you can ignore the instructions below.

Before proceeding with the numbered steps given above, first execute the following instructions. Click on the Disk Utility window and then press the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> key combination to insure the proper sidebar is displayed, as shown below.

> Note: Your container numbering may different.

[image]

Next, highlight the container for the `Untitled` volume shown in the sidebar, then select the `Erase` button. For `Format:`, select the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`, as shown below.

[image]

Finally, select the `Erase` button in the popup window. When finished, select the `Done` button. I needed to quit and open the Disk Utility to see the results. The `Untitled` volume should no longer be in a container, as shown below.

[image]

You can now proceed with the numbered steps given above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok You have no chance, your 75 Go space on Volume Untitled can only be added to the Container disk2 (Volume Project) and i suppose it's not your choice.

But but but, there is a way to repair this :

First you clone (with Carbon Copy Cloner free 1 mouth in test period) your Volume Project on Volume Untitled. **Keep in mind in CCC to deactivate the SafetyNet option for the Target Volume.**

After this, you rename Volume disk2s1 as Untitled and Volume disk1s1 as Project.

You can umount the Volume disk2s1

```
diskutil umount disk2s1
```

an after test if the new Volume Project is good and if ok, you give me the result of

```
diskutil list
```

and i give you the commands to add the 75 Go space of Untitled at your Container system